# Can't get INNER JOIN to join another table with PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am working on a PHP script and want to make an INNER JOIN so I can `SELECT` data from another table where the `id` (in `theList` table) and the `postid` (in the `post_rating`) table are the same.

I believe the code should look something like this:

```
INNER JOIN post_rating ON theList.id=post_rating.postid
```

Below is the code I am working with. I have added a `$join` variable.

For some reason it is not working! When I try to remove the $join and just have the `post_rating.postid` in the `SELECT` it doesn't work either - if that helps!

How can I get it to work! Many Thanks :)

```
<?php
    $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=myDB', 'root', 'root');
    $select = 'SELECT theList.id, theList.name, post_rating.postid';
    $from = ' FROM theList';
    $where = ' WHERE TRUE';
    $join = ' INNER JOIN post_rating ON theList.id=post_rating.postid';
    $opts = isset($_POST['filterOpts'])? $_POST['filterOpts'] : array('');
    if (in_array("pub", $opts)){
    $where .= " AND pub = 1";
    }
    if (in_array("bar", $opts)){
    $where .= " AND bar = 1";
    }
    if (in_array("restaurant", $opts)){
    $where .= " AND restaurant = 1";
    }
    if (in_array("club", $opts)){
    $where .= " AND club = 1";
    }

    $sql = $select . $from . $where . $join ;
    $statement = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $statement->execute();
    $results = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $json = json_encode($results);
    echo($json);
    ?>
```

Comment: You have a simple missing quote on line 3. Is that a mistake writing the question or a real mistake in your code

Comment: And then a trailing `,` at the end of your column name list

Comment: @RiggsFolly - Sorry they were both errors when I wrote the question. I have edited them now. Can you see why it's not working? Thanks!

Comment: Do you have an actual error message or does it just do nothing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where comes AFTER the JOIN in a valid query so amend your concatenation of the bits into `$sql`

```
$sql = $select . $from . $join . $where;
```

Comment: Thanks - Thats basically solved it. I should have asked before. If I wanted to add a line in like this $join = INNER JOIN ("SELECT post_rating.postid, AVG(post_rating.rating) FROM post_rating GROUP BY post_rating.postid") post_rating ON post_rating.postid=theList.id' - Would it work?

Comment: As long as it is a complete statement I think that should work

Comment: I have been trying it out and not getting anywhere! Do you have any pointers? I have also changed the 'INNER' to 'LEFT'.

Comment: Is it a simple case of using `"` in a double quoted string?

Comment: Changed them back and still shows nothing!

Comment: Otherwise make sure you are checking for errors in prepare and execute or setting exceptions. Then look at the error message

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will fix it for you, there could be some other issue but try:

`$sql = $select . $from . $join . $where;`